# How does stringstream works with operators << and >>?

Tags: c++, stringstream

Input would be something like : 07:10
I'm getting correct value for hour but for min, I'm getting weird values.

```
void timeConversion(string s) 
{
    int hour,min;
    
    stringstream ss;
    ss << s.substr(0,2);
    ss >> hour;
    cout << hour <<endl;
    
    ss << s.substr(3,2);
    ss >> min;
    cout << min<<endl;    
}
```

Comment: why use the stream in the first place? `hour` is just `s.substr(0,2)` and `min` is `s.substr(3,2)`, no?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number They are probably not aware of any other way to do the type conversion. Rudransh Srivastava: You can convert a (sub-)string directly to an integer with `std::stoi`.

Comment: You need a `ss.clear()` (or something else that resets the read/write positions and/or clears the "eof" flag) after the first read and before the second write.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I need the integer, just posted the problematic part of the function here.

Comment: @user17732522 yup saw stoi. Learning C++ and want to go with a way applicable for both int and double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing input and output like this is problematic. The initial extraction of `hour` sets the `eofbit`, which means when you try to extract `min` it immediately fails.

You can add `ss.clear()` to reset the flags.

```
void timeConversion(std::string s) 
{
    int hour,min;
    
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << s.substr(0,2);
    ss >> hour;
    std::cout << hour << std::endl;
    ss.clear();

    ss << s.substr(3,2);
    ss >> min;
    std::cout << min << std::endl;    
}
```

Or you use separate streams

```
void timeConversion(std::string s) 
{
    int hour,min;
    
    std::stringstream { s.substr(0,2) } >> hour;
    std::stringstream { s.substr(3,2) } >> min;

    std::cout << hour << std::endl << min << std::endl;    
}
```

Or you could use a different conversion function

```
void timeConversion(std::string s) 
{
    int hour = std::stoi(s.substr(0,2));
    int min = std::stoi(s.substr(3,2));

    std::cout << hour << std::endl << min << std::endl;    
}
```

Aside: I'd recommend using `std::string_view` to avoid copying segments of strings, it has the same methods as a `const std::string`

Comment: I would add that to avoid the `stringstream cast` pattern in general there is also `boost::lexical_cast`.

Comment: @TimonvanderBerg What's the advantage of using boost::lexical_cast over stringstream cast ?

Comment: @RudranshSrivastava Brevity and clarity.